# nodejs 16.14 - lastest version pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I don't have a strong web development background, but I have inherited a basic nodejs web server after our web developer left a few years ago.

We had a very old versin of nodejs back from 2018 and for some reason after a server reboot nodejs has been updated to the latest version 16.14
This has caused a number of issues in other packages (I'm actually suprises as much of the website runs then does not)

Anyway, I was having an issue with pg-promise library just not working.  No errors just nothing really.

This is what I was just trying to call just as a testing option at the entry of the website, but neither of these blocks get called.

```
const pipeDB = pipe(pipe_default_config);
pipeDB.connect()
.then(function(obj)
{
    console.log("connection ok")
    console.log(obj.client.serverVersion);
    obj.done();
})
.catch(function(error)
{
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
});
```

This was all working before the Node update - I assume that its just an old versin of pg-promise from 2018 also, so was looking to getting it updated also.

I downloaded the lastest from the git hub (https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) copied it into the modules folder - I still have the original pg-promise module folder so I can revert etc.

I am still getting no response from pg-promise, if there is anyone who can offer a suggestion that would be fantastic.

Comment: What output do you get from `console.log(pipeDB.$config.version)`?

Comment: @vitaly-t - current version is outputted as 10.11.1

Comment: Thank you @vitaly-t! The new version works also with (Node.js, v18) - perfect! :-)